# jQuery UI DatePicker - selecting date sets day, month, but current year

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jQUI DatePicker (DP) with month a year select boxes.

1. When DP is open you can see month (June), year (1912):

[image]

2. Then I choose date (Jun 7, 1912):

[image]

3. And this is what I get all the time (I've found the same bug a year ago):

[image]

The selected date is Jun 7, **2012** instead of Jun 7, **1912**.

Is it possible to achieve correct year (it's not working only if you don't change the year - if you change the year, e.g. to 1950, you get Jun 7, 1950)

Thanks for help ion advance.

Comment: try to use some different data picker... simple,, because you found same error before year ago. but you didn't try to resolve this.. like here

Comment: Easy to implement.. http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/doc/ try this

Comment: Hm, I think it's the only solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to use that datepicker before and it didn't work out. I had to change to [Primefaces Calendar](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/calendarMinMax.jsf) ([this one is what you're trying to achieve](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/calendarLocalization.jsf)) which is way more easier and much more nicer :)

Comment: Look nice...but for jQUI DatePicker you can find a lot things to customize etc. and I'm using the whole UI Pack, so it's more convenient for me :)

Comment: @Peter O. just sayin' that with primefaces you can achieve that pretty easy. take a look at [this example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/calendarLocalization.jsf)